# Comparing the values of one Combo box with another combo box value and grayed out if it is same

Tags: javascript

I have two combo box.

First Combo box ("Comb1") is having the following values.

Select,Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4

Second Combo box ("Comb2") is having the following values.

Test1,Test3

Through Javascript, I want to take each value of Comb2 and compare with the value of Comb1 and if it is same, the corresponding value of Comb1, should be grayout ( or non selectable). So, in this case, Test1 and Test 3 of the COmb1 should be grayed out.

Kindly help me out,as I am stuck to this point.
Thanks